# Spring Security logout redirect not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, spring-security, logout

I have this configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http
      .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout");
    ...
}
```

According to documentation The default redirect is to `/login?logout` but I just get `204 No Content`. The same happens if I set a custom success url:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http
      .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/myUrl");
    ...
}
```

I get to redirect if I specifically set the default success handler myself:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http
      .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/myUrl");
      .logoutSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler());
    ...
}
```

But still it redirects to `"/"` which is its (`SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler`) default url.

Comment: what does your request look like

Comment: and regarding your last case the documentation states `Let’s you specify a custom LogoutSuccessHandler. If this is specified, logoutSuccessUrl() is ignored`

Comment: Check if you send Rest request. Reference https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3902

Comment: @Toerktumlare I'm using postman so: https://imgur.com/a/OPc4SCE

Comment: So the problem was using Postman. I found that adding the header "Accept: text/plain" for example solved the issue. Thanks guys